# Clear contents of range including filtered data VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following statement to delete the contents of the cells within a range, but it fails to delete the contents of the filtered cells:

```
wbMM.Sheets("SS 18 MESES").Range("A:A").Clear
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Unfilter then clear not an option?

Comment: @BigBen Not in this case.

Comment: @BigBen Repeat the exact same line?

Comment: @BigBen It didn't work, the content of the filtered cells was not cleared :o

Comment: Yeah you're going to have to go with the proposed answer - sorry ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This will have the same effect as clearing the cells:

```
Sub KillA()
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

You will end up with an empty column **A**.

Comment: I have formulas in other sheets depending on the values of the cells within that range, so this would not work

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove filtering first?

```
With wbMM.Sheets("SS 18 MESES")
    If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If

    .Range("A:A").Clear
End With
```

Comment: As I answered another comment suggesting this idea, this is not an option in this case

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `"A:A"` Set your `Range`, `Autofilter` then loop through each cell in the range and clear.

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    With rng
        .AutoFilter 1, "x"

        For Each cel In rng
            cel.Clear
        Next cel
    End With
```